# How to Modify Props of Non-immediate Children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am transferring my site from a LAMP stack to a MERN stack. On the old site, I had a dropdown where a button would toggle the display of a `div` of one of its parents siblings. The structure looked like this:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-option">Option 1</div>
    <div class="header-option" id="toggle-dropdown">Option 2</div>
    <div class="header-option">Option 3</div>
</div>
<div id="dropdown-content">
    Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

I would use JQuery to detect a click on `#toggle-dropdown` and then toggle the display of `#dropdown-content`. I turned this into a reusable plugin which could be used throughout the site. I would now like to do something like this in React with a reusable component. But I cannot seem to find the best practice for accessing and modifying the props of non-immediate children. I would of course wrap all of this in a `<Dropdown>` component to handle the state and to be able to abstract the process.

What I have thought of and found so far:

1. Recursing through the children, and their children, and so on, looking for a displayName and then cloning the child; but I don't believe this works in production.
2. Taking JSX as a Header and Footer prop to `Dropdown`, and then attempting to generate the `DropdownButton` and `DropdownContent` within components with the appropriate props; I feel like this would be a very inefficient, undesirable solution to something that I feel should be relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you have:

```
<Header>
   <Option />
   <Option onClick={this.handleDropdownclick} props={props}>
      <Dropdown>
   </Option>
   <Option />
</Header>
```

right?
just pass the onClick handler to option you want, no?
Or didn't I understand what are you asking?

If your tree is very deep and you don't want to pass manually each prop, may be use Context? https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer